# Keys '9', 'o', 'L', '.' not working in MacBook pro

Tags: keyboard, hardware

All of a sudden my keyboard keys 'o', '9', 'L', '.', '-' and right arrow stopped working. Even on Keyboard viewer when pressed respective keys are not getting highlighted. In Safe mode, Recovery mode they are not working. I've read it may be due to dust or it's a hardware problem. Kindly help about probable fix and since the keys are in same column , is it due to a connector issue?

Info:
MacBook Pro 2020 Model

Processor : 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5

Comment: Keys in a vertical row that don't work is usually caused by a hardware problem. Take it to an Apple Store or other repair shop.

Comment: Ah that's sad to know